# Python dictionary caesar: look up a numerical value, +1, then return its associated key

Tags: python, string, dictionary

This is a really interesting caesar-cipher problem.

Here's my dictionary:

```
**{'v': 22, 'g': 7, 'w': 23, 'h': 8, 'a': 1, 'm': 13, 'c': 3, 'o': 15, 'd': 4, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 'j': 10, 't': 20, 'f': 6, 'k': 11, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, 'l': 12, ' ': 0, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'q': 17, 'n': 14, 'i': 9, 'p': 16, 'x': 24}**
```

Obviously, dictionaries are un-ordered. They're not organised alphabetically or numerically, only by pair.

I have to:

1. Look up each letter in a string("hi my name is caesar") in this dictionary
2. Return an encoded message. If the letter is 'a', this is value 1 in the dictionary. However, my code would be to print the letter 'b' which is value 2 in the dictionary.

I've seen examples of caesars using lists (which can be ordered by me), but not trying to navigate **dictionaries** in this way...

I will post my answer as soon as I have figured this out. At the moment I am just puzzled by it. Writing this down has helped clarify the steps that might be needed.

NB I think " " turns to "a" if the code works correctly.

expected output: "ijanzaobnajtadbftbt"

Comment: You should show your [mcve] that attempts to use this dict.

Comment: So... are you planning to self answer this question or do you want us to spoil the solution? (edit: also, what's the expected output/result for `"hi my name is caesar"`?)

Comment: not sure if this is SO material...

Comment: So if I understand correctly: I have letter `a` and in the encoded version this should be a 2? What happens for example with y? Does it become a 26?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=caeser+python

Comment: @timgeb thanks - I'm not reading other people's suggestions until I have done more on my own, to force more learning- but feel free to spoil the solution if you wish! I'm sure yours will be way better than mine. *Covers screen*. I'm going away now for a bit.

Comment: @timgeb I've just come back to this problem after a break and wish I hadn't! I've managed to make it do this (which is not what it's supposed to be doing at all): "h - hi - hi - hi m- hi my - hi my - hi my n - hi my na - hi my nam - hi my name - hi my name  - hi my name I - hi my name is - hi my name is c- " etc etc ;) will give it another shot.

Answer (score 1):

okay here is my take

```
d = {'v': 22, 'g': 7, 'w': 23, 'h': 8, 'a': 1, 'm': 13, 'c': 3, 'o': 15, 'd': 4, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 'j': 10, 't': 20, 'f': 6, 'k': 11, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, 'l': 12, ' ': 0, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'q': 17, 'n': 14, 'i': 9, 'p': 16, 'x': 24}

sentence = 'hi my name is caesar'

for char in ''.join(sentence.split()):
    print(d[chr(ord(char) + 1)], end=' ')
```

Output

```
9 10 14 26 15 2 14 6 10 20 4 2 6 20 2 19
```

Comment: You are not using `d` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reversed dictionary and use that to build your encrypted string. The reversed dictionary will be helpful to look up the character corresponding to the "next" number for a given character:

```
d = {'v': 22, 'g': 7, 'w': 23, 'h': 8, 'a': 1, 'm': 13, 'c': 3, 'o': 15, 'd': 4, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 'j': 10, 't': 20, 'f': 6, 'k': 11, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, 'l': 12, ' ': 0, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'q': 17, 'n': 14, 'i': 9, 'p': 16, 'x': 24}
reverse_d = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}

sentence = 'hi my name is caesar'
encrypted = ''.join([reverse_d.get(d[c] + 1, reverse_d[0]) for c in sentence])

print(encrypted)
# ijanzaobnfajtadbftbs
```

Note that I use the default key `0` if a number isn't found in `reverse_d`.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary always just denotes the number of the character in the alphabet, you don't even need the dictionary and this is a one-liner:

```
sentence = 'hi my name is caesar'
encoded = ''.join([chr(ord(c)+1) if ord(c)>96 and ord(c)<122 else "a" for c in sentence])
```

This gives

```
In [14]: encoded
Out[14]: 'ijanzaobnfajtadbftbs'
```

But for a general solution, slider's approach is the most elegant, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

```
message = "hi my name is caesar"
alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
positions = {' ': 0,'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5,'f': 6,'g': 7,'h': 8,'i': 9,'j': 10,'k': 11,'l': 12,'m': 13,'n': 14,'o': 15,'p': 16,'q': 17,'r': 18,'s': 19,'t': 20,'u': 21,'v': 22,'w': 23,'x': 24,'y': 25,'z': 26}

# STEP ONE is to make an empty list to add your characters to. (Lists work well with dictionaries) 

encryptlist = []

# STEP TWO locate the value of the 'r' in caesar.

for chars in message:
Num = positions[chars]
```

Num returns: 18

```
#STEP THREE encrypt by one step (+1). You can keep the result within 0-26 using result % 27

encoded_Num = (Num + 1) % 27

#STEP 4 encrypt as a list

encryptlist.append(alphabet[encoded_Num])
```

encryptlist now returns
['i', 'j', 'a', 'n', 'z', 'a', 'o', 'b', 'n', 'f', 'a', 'j', 't', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'f', 't', 'b', 's']

```
# convert the list to a string

encoded_message = "".join(encryptlist)

encoded_message
```

returns: 'ijanzaobnfajtadbftbs' which is the expected output